# kml hide polygon at high zoom level

Tags: google-maps, hide, zooming, kml, polygon

I have a Google map with points and polygons defined in a KML file and with points only defined in another KML file. I want to be able to load one or the other depending on the zoom level and have tried variations of the following:

```
var url_end = "?nocache=" + (new Date()).valueOf();
var NWlayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  if (map.getZoom() > 18){
    url: "http://www.example.com/Google/ShowPointsOnly.kml" + url_end
  }
  else {
    url: "http://www.example.com/Google/ShowAll.kml" + url_end
  }
});
NWlayer.setMap(map);
```

... but depending on the variation that I try I get points and polygons regardless of the zoom level or else I get no map at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an event listener for the [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) zoom_changed event

```
var NWlayer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    preserveViewport: true,
    url: "http://www.example.com/Google/ShowPointsOnly.kml" + url_end
  });
var NWlayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    preserveViewport: true,
    url: "http://www.example.com/Google/ShowAll.kml" + url_end
  });
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  if (map.getZoom() > 18){
    NWlayer1.setMap(map);
    NWlayer2.setMap(null);
  } else {
    NWlayer1.setMap(null);
    NWlayer2.setMap(map); 
  }
});
```

Comment: By changing it thus, the page loads without any points or polygons. Zooming one level then adds the points and polygons but zooming beyond level 18 makes it jump back to level 15. The page is at http://www.noosawaters.org/Google/noosawaters_test2.html. The KML files are correct because they load properly when stand-alone without any frills.

Comment: To get one of the layers to show by default, call setMap(map) on it when you initialize the map.  To stop the KmlLayer from automatically zooming to show its content, add the [{preserveViewport: true}](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions) option to the KmlLayer

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks. This is a steep but interesting learning curve.